# Haskell simple compilation bug

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run this code:

```
let coins = [50, 25, 10, 5, 2,1]

let candidate = 11

calculate :: [Int]
calculate = [ calculate (x+candidate) | x <- coins, x > candidate]
```

I've read some tutorials, and it worked out ok.
I'm trying to solve some small problems to give-me a feel of the language. But I'm stuck at this.

```
test.hs:3:0: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

Can anyone tell me why? I've started with haskell today so please go easy on the explanations.

I've tried to run it like:

```
runghc test.hs
ghc test.hs
```

but with:

```
ghci < test.hs
```

it gives this one:

```
<interactive>:1:10: parse error on input `='
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Top level declarations don't need 'let'.  You probably want:

```
coins = [50, 25, 10, 5, 2,1]

candidate = 11
```

2) Calculate is explicitly typed as a list and used as a function.

Here is where you say calculate is a list of integers:

```
calculate :: [Int]
```

And inside the list comprehension you used `calculate (x+candidate)`, but you already explicitly made calculate a list and not a function - so this can not work.

```
calculate = [ calculate (x+candidate) | x <- coins, x > candidate]
```

Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
newCoins = [ x + candidate | x <- coins, x > candidate]
```

It would help if you explained more of what you want as a result.

Comment: I'm following this: http://www.haskell.org/~pairwise/intro/section1.html and I saw some examples of stuff like that so i was trying it out

Comment: @fmsf: The type you gave for calculate indicates that it is a (constant) list of Ints. But definition you gave for `calculate` appears to be a function (not a list) taking an `[Int]` argument `coins` and performing some kind of calculation on it. So type should be something like `calculate :: [Int] -> [Int]`. But the recursive call to `calculate (x + calculate)` still doesn't make much sense, as that would imply that `calculate` takes an Int rather than a list.

Comment: I can't explain directly what i want to do that would be cheating, has I'm doing it as an alternative implementation for a univ assignement. but you helped a lot tks

Answer (score 3):

I'm also pretty new to haskell, but this is what I have gathered so far

In ghci, you cannot define a function **without** `let`

In a `.hs` file, you cannot define a function **with** `let`

Answer (score 1):

Using `let` is tricky. In a Haskell `.hs` file that you intend to compile with `ghc` or to run with `runghc` or `runhaskell`, you don't need to use `let` to define values and functions. So you should just do:

```
test = ...
candidate = ...
calculate = ...
```

In a `do` block, or when using the interpreter which actually runs your code as though it were written inside a `do` block, whenever you define values and functions, you should use the `let` keyword. So inside a `do` block or within a `ghci` session, you might do

```
let test = ...
let candidate = ...
let calculate = ...
```

As one final note, you might use the keyword `let` outside of a `do` block or `ghci` session when making a temporary value to be used within a larger definition, such as:

```
calculate =
    let test = ... in
    let candidate = ... in
    ... {stuff that uses test and candidate}
```

Comment: It's not so much that using `let` is tricky as just that the GHCi interpreter is tricky. If you ignore GHCi, `let` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Some functional languages require all definitions to begin with `let` or `letrec`. Haskell makes things more concise, but includes the `let` keyword and even requires it in certain cases. I would say that for someone just starting out in functional programming with Haskell, given the `where` keyword, `let` would rarely come up outside `do` blocks because Haskell simply has you write `{name} = {definition}` throughout.

Comment: in your last code block, you could have used one `let/in`, also `test` would be in scope in `candidate` and vice versa, as well as both being available in the `in` section

Comment: @jberryman, that is absolutely correct. Thank you for your suggestions. The only reason I didn't write it as you suggested is that I wanted to focus purely on `let` rather than on the code as a whole - I wanted to use `let` in the simplest, clearest ways I could, rather than write clear, idiomatic Haskell code.